# Token based Payment Processing in Netsuite

Tags: token, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, netsuite

Does anyone have any idea implementing `Token based Payments` in **Netsuite**. Instead of storing the CC in customer record for accepting payments, we want to tokenize the CC for accepting customer payments. We are using MeS gateway for our Payment transactions. I surf but didn't get any source relevant to the process/steps illustrating the use of tokens in Netsuite. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after waiting awhile and surfing here & there finally I got some reply from Netsuite folks stating :

> Currently NetSuite does not support Tokenization with Merchant E Solution. We have an existing enhancement for this, Enhancement # 205234. NetSuite does support tokenization with regards to CyberSource.
>   To get a better undestanding how Tokenization works within NetSuite you can watch a short Video by visiting SuiteAnswers. SuiteAnswers article 'ERP: Payment Enhancements' ID: 41359. Just forward the video to 39:13 (Page 22).